# FFMPEG: error on audio and video combined

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, command

I have a command to combine a audio only file and a video only file, but there is an error in executing it.

```
  [h264 @ 0xca23d40]brainfart cropping not supported, this could look slightly wrong ...
  [h264 @ 0xca23d40]left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 0
  [h264 @ 0xca23d40]error while decoding MB 0 0, bytestream (134838)
```

Here is my command:

```
  ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -acodec copy -pass 1 -vcodec copy -b 120000 -s 2560x1024 -f avi -threads 0 -y combine2.mp4
```

This works in my windows PC but does not work on my linux. It generate a result the audio sounds fine but the video does not move. It's as if it just one picture.

Help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my bad. The audio that I was trying to combine with the video is corrupted that is why its showing such notification.